# Fill dropdown menu according to onchange action PHP

Tags: php, sql, onchange

I need to fill a dropdown menu from a database table then according to selection in this dropdown menu, in the same page I have to fill another dropdown menu by using sql queries and variable coming from previous dropdown menu. I found a tutorial about that but in ajax I take xmlhttp notfound error. Is there another solution method for making this properly?

Comment: Using ajax is normal way of doing that. If you don't want to use an ajax you can store the data from the db table in javascript array before rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, searched around the net but couldn't come out with a working answer. I handled the solution by getting all the data for all tables from the database, and do the fillings with them.